# How to Populate Range Address which was Stored in Array

Tags: vba, excel

i writing code for adding two cells and cell addresses stored in array. the below part of code showing the error - how to retrieve the cell addresses from array and adding those cells - please suggest the correction

```
Sub test()

    Dim A1add(1 To 100) As String
    lrw = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    A1add(1) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
    A1add(2) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sheets(1).Range("b2")
    Set add1 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sheets(1).Range("C2")


    Select Case 2

    Case 2

        With add1.Resize(lrw)
            .NumberFormat = "0"
            .Formula = "= ( " & A1add(1).Address(False, False) & "+" & A1add(2).Address(False, False) & " )"
        End With

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set add1 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sheets(1).Range("C2") `.... forgot  to mention `.`

Comment: Declare lrow as Long and add1 as range. Select case case needs a condition to test for.

Comment: @rosetta - done

Comment: @QHarr  The way the OP has the Select case is a test only.  It is like saying `If 2=2 then` and is perfectly valid.  The Op is supplying a minimal test code that shows the error they are getting, not actual code.

Comment: Acknowledged. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `A1add(1) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sheets(1).Range("A2")`

Puts the value of the cell in the array not the range or the address of the range.  That information is not stored in the array.

And `ActiveSheet.Sheets(1).` refers to two sheets.  remove one.

In this case you would want:

> `A1add(1) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Address(0,0)`

Then the formula would use that alone.

> `"= ( " & A1add(1) & "+"`

So:

```
Sub test()

    Dim A1add(1 To 100) As String
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim Add1 As Range

    lrw = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    A1add(1) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Address(0, 0)
    A1add(2) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Address(0, 0)
    Set add1 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C2")


    Select Case 2

    Case 2

        With add1.Resize(lrw - 1)
            .NumberFormat = "0"
            .Formula = "= ( " & A1add(1) & "+" & A1add(2) & " )"
        End With

    End Select

End Sub
```